# Как передать ImageView из RecyclerView в другой фрагмент?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-intent

У меня есть RecyclerView, в котором хранятся иконки. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на item, ImageView передавалось в другой фрагмент. Я использовал передачу через Битмап, но что-то не юзается.

> Вот мой код:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;

public class AimsMetkaAdapterIcons extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    Bitmap[] iconList;
    private static final String TAG = "NigersBek";

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_SECTION = 0;

    private List<SectionImage> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context ctx;

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, SectionImage obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public AimsMetkaAdapterIcons(Context context, List<SectionImage> items){
        this.items = items;
        ctx = context;
    }

    public class AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView image;
        public View lyt_parent;


        public AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            lyt_parent = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);

        }


    }

    public static class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View title_section;

        public SectionViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title_section = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.title_section);
        }
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid_sectioned, viewGroup, false);
            vh = new AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_section, viewGroup, false);
            vh = new SectionViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final SectionImage s = items.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "Niger is workq1" );
        if (viewHolder instanceof AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Niger is work2" );
            AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder view = (AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder) viewHolder;
            displayImageOriginal(ctx,view.image,s.image);

            view.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Niger is workgcfvhbjnk" );
                    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, s, position);

                    }
//                    
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DiaryFragment.class);
                    Bitmap bitmam = Bitmap.createBitmap(((AimsMetkaAdapterIconsViewHolder) viewHolder).image.getDrawingCache());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmam.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
                    i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
                    ctx.startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        } else {
            SectionViewHolder view = (SectionViewHolder) viewHolder;

        }

        if (s.section) {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        } else {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position).section ? VIEW_SECTION : VIEW_ITEM;
    }
    public static void displayImageOriginal(Context ctx, ImageView img, int url) {

            Glide.with(ctx)
                    .load(url)
                    .transition(withCrossFade())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .into(img);

    }
    public  static void niga(){

    }

}
```

> Получение ImageView в другом фрагменте:

```
if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
            ImageView BottomRightImageView = (ImageView)RootView1.findViewById(R.id.icon_metka_mm);
            Bitmap bitmam = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
            BottomRightImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmam);}
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение передавать меж экранами `Bitmap` - не правильное.

1. Меж экранами по фэн-шую надо передавать ID объектов, а не сами объекты.
2. Если передавать тяжёлые объекты, то вы быстро упрётесь в лимит на 1Mb данных для передачи их этим способом.

Вам надо передавать на другой экран что-то простое, например ссылку на картинку и там её по этой ссылке отображать.